# Super Mario grows effect in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I wanna to implement an effect similiar to that which happens when super Mario eats the mushroom and grows. Should happen when a sprite collides with the main sprite. How can I achieve this in an easy way with the AndEngine ?

Comment: Try asking this on the gamedev overflow site.

Comment: why no link for that question?

Comment: are you using the Box2D extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register to your "Mario" sprite SclaeAtModifier:

```
final Sprite entity= new Strite(x, y, textureRegion);
final ScaleAtModifier entityModifier = new ScaleAtModifier(10 /*Durarion*/, 1/*from*/, 2/*to*/, 0/*scale center X*/, 0 /*scale center Y*/);

// register modifier
entity.registerEntityModifier(entityModifier);
```

If your need not linear scale modification add specific IEaseFunction to ScaleAtModifier

Comment: Works for me! , 
Should marked as the correct answer :)  


 @Claudio Ferraro